# Same docker image tag is not getting overwritten

Tags: docker, artifactory

I am uploading same docker image tag with latest changes, However Jfrog artifactory
not updating the image tag updation date and time. It still remain same as the create date.

Comment: Have you enabled artifact redeployment for the repository?

Comment: @AntonioPetricca No, how can i do that. I didn't get any option from artifactory dashboard.

Comment: Does the create date on the tag in the registry match the create date when you inspect the image?